# pass data to spring mvc controller by ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

How can I normaly pass data to MVc controller action by ajax
Now in my js file

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:url,
    data:     {
            start_date:   scheduler.getEvent(id).start_date,
            end_date:  scheduler.getEvent(id).end_date,
            text: scheduler.getEvent(id).text,
            userId: userId
    },
    success:function(result){
        if(combo.getActualValue() != null){
            getUserEvents(id);
        }
        else{
            $.ajax({
                url:"/WebElanceSh/events",
                success:function(result){
                    json = result;
                    scheduler.parse(json, "json");
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and in my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "events/add/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addEvent(@RequestBody  String start_date,
                     @RequestBody  String end_date,
                     @RequestBody  String text,
                     @RequestBody  Integer userId){
    Event event = new Event(text,start_date,end_date);

    if(userId == -1){
         TestData.getInstance().AddEvent(-1, event);

    }
    else {
        TestData.getInstance().AddEvent(userId, event);

    }

}
```

But I have always have
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: are passing `url` right in `url:url`?

Comment: What are you passing through the second ajax call. That one in the else statement?

Comment: it is doesn't metter because it crashes on the first ajax

Comment: I think that your problem is the same as this:

[HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type for AJAX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14863274/http-status-415-unsupported-media-type-for-ajax-call-in-jquery-to-restful-ws-i)

Answer (score 1):

Model an Object that match the ajax request, then use it as request parameter:#

```
public class MyCommandObject {
   private Date start_date;
   private Date end_date;
   private String text;
   private Integer userId;

   /** Constructor wihtout parameter needed. */
   public MyCommandObject() {}

   Getter and Setter
}


@RequestMapping(value = "events/add/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addEvent(@RequestBody  MyCommandObject command){ ... }
```

Comment: Maybe your date is not in that format that is expected by spring. Try to use type `String` instead of `Date` in the `MyCommandObject`

Comment: Of course you have to add the json jackson libary to your application